# "cordova-hcp server" not starting the Hot Code Push server

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Since this morning though, the [HCP server](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push-cli) refuses to start. I tried several thing, including :

- killing the service which I didn't find
- restarting my machine
- reinstalling cordova-hot-code-push-cli
- reinstalling ngrok

I am kind of stuck... What happens is the following :
Here is what happens :

```
[root@happydev mlb_cordova]# cordova-hcp server
Running server
[root@happydev mlb_cordova]#
```

I am not sure where to look for logs. If one could give me some tip that could get me going. Any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The error was coming from `ngrok` which stopped supporting version 1.X

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push-cli/issues/47) and [here](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push-cli/pull/48#event-601520231)